# Additional custom field created by Salesforce when change field type

Tags: tooling-api

I am playing around with Salesforce tooling API recently. And there is one custom field I created under standard object 'Account' with field type 'Text', API 'CusField__c'. When I change this custom field type from 'Text' to 'Currency', except this custom field, Salesforce also create one additional custom field automatically with developername '_tc__00NW2000000INuD__0'.

This one additional field is not shown at UI but it does appear when you query via tooling api.

And when I change this currency field type to 'checkbox', it automatically create another customfield record with developername '_tc__00NW2000000INuD__6'. I was wondering what is happening at the back end and what is the purpose of those fields, thank you.

[image]